# How to make composition query based on POST data

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm stuck, can't find a way to solve this task.
I have a simple search form with 4 fields, and can't do composite query based on it.

```
form.py

class ViewerForm(forms.Form):
    text_search = forms.CharField(required=False)
    birthday_search = forms.DateField(required=False)
    study_from_search = forms.DateField(required=False)
    study_to_search = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

I tried to do things like that, but it doesn't work properly.

```
view.py
    def viewer(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ViewerForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                persons_list = Person.objects.all()
                query = []
                if len(request.POST['text_search']):
                    text = request.POST['text_search']
                    query.append(persons_list.filter(Q(fio__contains=text) | Q(sex__contains=text) | Q(mobile_number__contains=text) | Q(group__contains=text) | Q(edu_organization__contains=text)))

                if len(request.POST['text_search']):
                    birthday = request.POST['birthday_search']
                    query.append(persons_list.filter(Q(birthday_date__exact=birthday)))

                if len(request.POST['study_from_search']):
                    study_from_search = request.POST['study_from_search']
                    query.append(persons_list.filter(Q(birthday_date__exact=study_from_search)))

                if len(request.POST['study_to_search']):
                    study_to_search = request.POST['study_to_search']
                    query.append(persons_list.filter(Q(period_of_study_to__exact=study_to_search)))
                persons_list.filter(query)
```

How to make query based on POST data, if data in a filed is exist then do some filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
query = []
if len(request.POST['text_search']):
     text = request.POST['text_search']
     query.append(Q(fio__contains=text) | Q(sex__contains=text) | Q(mobile_number__contains=text) | Q(group__contains=text) | Q(edu_organization__contains=text))

if len(request.POST['text_search']):
    birthday = request.POST['birthday_search']
    query.append(Q(birthday_date__exact=birthday))

if len(request.POST['study_from_search']):
    study_from_search = request.POST['study_from_search']
    query.append(Q(birthday_date__exact=study_from_search))

if len(request.POST['study_to_search']):
    study_to_search = request.POST['study_to_search']
    query.append(Q(period_of_study_to__exact=study_to_search))

persons_list.filter(*query)
```

You need to [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q). It shows how to compose Q objects.

Note: I think there are typos in your code, since you do a birthday search if there's a `text_search` and you match the `birthday_date` to `study_from_search`.

Note2: You shouldn’t check `len()` but check whether a value is set like this:

```
study_from_search = request.POST.get('study_from_search')
if study_from_search:
    query.append(Q(...))
```

Comment: it still gets me an error (ValidationError at /["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]) when I try to use only text_search field. I think this is because I do empty search on date fileds.

Comment: print your request.POST to see what's being submitted. The issue is with your form right now, not with the query (which is a different question entirely so you should create a different question if you're having issues posting and validating a DateField).

Comment: This error is about this line persons_list.filter(*query). Btw I fill only text_search field, others 3 are empty.

Comment: That’s because `len(request.POST[‘birthday’]` is always true. Make the changes I mention in the notes.